# Retrieve selected feature on ArcGIS Online as string?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

For now I am trying to create a webmap with the ArcGIS API (4.x) for JavaScript. I have a bit understanding of the workings of JavaScript, however I couldn't find code in which it's possible to select a feature (let's say a building) on the web map and ***return a string*** when selecting on this feature (such as the name of selected feature. I want to use the string of the ***name*** (e.g.) for another action.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE; thanks for taking the [tour]. Please [edit] your question to include your code thus far and indicate what's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Setup the click event (`view.on("pointer-down", function(event) { ... });`), and in that click event use `view.hitTest(event).then(function(hitTestResponse) { ... });` and within that function, you can get the attributes. A good example is [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/view-hittest/index.html). Good luck!